# Discord.js how can I send message and check server id

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

"Discord.js version 11.4.2"

I have a question if I want to create a command such as command check server id if server id is 426626817596850177
then it will send a message to channel "verify server" if id server isn't 426626817596850177 then "can't verify server"

```
if(message.content === "a check"){
  const msg = await message.channel.send("Checking Server.....")
  msg.edit("verify server")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `message.guild.id` for this.
I use array of guild`s id because maybe more then 1 server can be verified.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === 'a check') {
        message.channel.send('Checking Server.....').then(msg => {
            if (['426626817596850177'].includes(message.guild.id)) {
                msg.edit('verify server');
            } else {
                msg.edit("can't verify server");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(message.content === "a check"){
    const msg = await message.channel.send("Checking Server.....")
    if (message.guild.id == "426626817596850177") {
      msg.edit("verify server");
    } else {
      msg.edit("can't verify server");
    };
  };
```